# Symfony 2 Many to Many and custom sql

Tags: php, sql, sql-server, symfony

I have problem with my custom sql where I need to use many to many relationship.

I have a few tables:
- attributeproduct
- attribute
- product
- attributegroup

and three entities
- attribute
- product
- attributegroup

Now I create query :

```
'SELECT a.name, ag.name as "group" FROM produkt p'
            . ' JOIN attributeprodukt ap ON (p.id = ap.produkt_id)'
            . ' JOIN attribute a ON (a.id = ap.attribute_id)'
            . ' JOIN attributegroup ag ON (ag.id = a.group_id)'
            . ' WHERE p.id = :id'
            . ' ORDER BY ag.name ASC, a.name ASC';
```

When I testing it on Windows (XAMPP) everything is ok but when I send files to server ( LINUX ). I got error :

> Base table or view not found: 1146 Table
>   'attributeprodukt' doesn't exist

My short code. Anyone can help me? ( I checked database and I have table attributeproduct

```
class attribute
{

/**
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="product", inversedBy="attributes", cascade={"persist"})
 * @ORM\JoinTable(name="attributeproduct")
 */
    protected $products;

/**
* @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="attributegroup", inversedBy="attributes")
*/
protected $group;

}


class produkt
{
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="attribute", mappedBy="products", cascade={"persist"})
     */
    protected $attributes;
}

class attributegroup
{
    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="attribute", mappedBy="group", cascade={"persist"}, orphanRemoval=true)
     * @OrderBy({"name" = "ASC"})
     */
    protected $attributes;
}
```

Comment: How are you using the query? createQuery(), createNativeQuery() or issuing your own prepared statement using the EntityManager's connection?

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to make JOIN on generated table name while you should apply JOIN on the entity classes with which your tables has been generated , because dql only recognizes the entity class not the generated tables. so your code should be something like as

```
      'SELECT a.name, ag.name FROM YourBundle:produkt p'
         ' JOIN YourBundle:attribute a ON (p.id = a.products)'
         ' JOIN YourBundle:attributegroup ag ON (ag.id = a.group)'
         ' WHERE p.id = :id'
         ' ORDER BY ag.name ASC, a.name ASC';
```

i m not good in dql query but my basic moto to say is that u should use entity classes parametes not the generated table's parameters ..